# Excel Freeze Panes Macro Issues

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm using win32com in python to modify excel workbooks. I would like to freeze cell C6, but the following code freezes cell P22. The actual value I give for `Range` doesn't seem to matter.

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
book = excel.Workbooks.Add()

excel.Range("C6").Select
excel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

Any idea what the issue is here?

Comment: Can you use `xlsxwriter`? That works without issue for me. If you like I'll write up an example in an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty deep into developing an application that uses win32com, so it wouldn't be worth switching at this point.

Comment: Perhaps insure that you are referencing the sheet on which the range is contained since there is no global/workbook level `Range("C6")`. Instead: `excel.Sheets(1).Range("C6").Select` or `excel.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C6").Select` This is just a guess though.

Comment: @JNevill, I tried this by deleting all but one worksheet. I get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that the value for `Range`, in your example being C6, matters, you need to add parentheses () after `Select`.

Your code being then:

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
book = excel.Workbooks.Add()

excel.Range("C6").Select() #add the () at the end here
excel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

For me, it freezes at J20 when I don't add the () after `Select`.

Regards.

Comment: T: What does it mean in Win32com with & without the () for Select and other methods for that matter?

Comment: @123456 honestly it is a bit old in my memory (haven't use this lib for a while), but I would say it is mostly a coding paradigm more than anything. In VBA, to call a function you don't need () while in python, you always need to use () to perform the methods and functions. so if you don't add the (), it returns the method but does not run it (sorry not really rigorous answer, hope it helps though)